# Failed to fetch in react js

Tags: reactjs, fetch

when i do call url https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com/posts , just get a failed fetch, i don't know what happened, help.

Code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import {useEffect} from 'react'
export default function App() {
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com/posts/6425abddd6e26eee1f7b5508')
      .then((res)=> res.json())
      .then((respuesta) => console.log(respuesta))
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at eval (App.js:5:5)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:26)
    at invokePassiveEffectMountInDEV (react-dom.development.js:25154:13)
    at invokeEffectsInDev (react-dom.development.js:27351:11)
    at commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV (react-dom.development.js:27330:7)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27056:5)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:14)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:26935:5)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:26682:5)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26117:3)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (react-dom.development.js:12042:22)
    at flushSync (react-dom.development.js:26201:7)
    at Object.scheduleRoot (react-dom.development.js:27810:5)
    at eval (react-refresh-runtime.development.js:280:17)
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.performReactRefresh (react-refresh-runtime.development.js:259:25)
    at eval (refresh-helper.js:13:20)
```

Comment: add catch block to see the error
`
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://serverbackend-br77.onrender.com/posts/6425abddd6e26eee1f7b5508')
      .then((res)=> res.json())
      .then((respuesta) => console.log(respuesta))
      .catch((err))=>console.log(err))
  })
`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the API that you're using here is giving 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).